# How can I expand a ListBox item to the side?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, listbox, listboxitem

I have a ListBox which contain text and image. When the user click on an Item I want that it will expand to the side and will show some more information.
I have tried to do it with Expander control, but it's does'nt expand over the ListBox border.
Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a classic master/detail type of user interface - the ListBox is the master, and you want some detail to show once the user selects an item.

If the tooltip suggestion from Notter is not suitable, then i would suggest that you have your expander control beside the ListBox, not inside of it. There are already a multitude of posts here on SO deailing with this (usually using the DataGrid as the master, but the concept is the same), [check out this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=master+detail+%5Bsilverlight%5D+listbox) and see if anything is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use a Popup/tooltip control (forgot it's name)
other than that, i can't think of anything that will do what you're asking, but i'm pretty sure anything you'll do won't have anything to do with the ListBox itself, but with the DataTemplate